# How to train a model to distinguish/categorize words by predefined meanings?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

Semantic analysis in deep learning and NLP is usually about the meaning of a whole sentence, such as sentiment analysis. In many cases, the meaning of a word can be understood by the sentence structure. For example,

> Can you tell this from that?
>
> Can you tell me something about this?

Is there any established method for training a model by a dataset of

```
word    meaning_id       sentence
tell    1                Can you tell this from that?
tell    2                Can you tell me something about this?
```

Note that the purpose is just to categorize words by predefined meanings/examples.

I use Stanford CoreNLP, but I doubt if there is such a possibility. Any deep learning program is OK.

Answer (score 0):

What I can think of is using contextualized WordEmbeddings. Those are embeddings for a word given its context. That means depending on the context, a word has another embedding. BERT generates such contexualized embeddings. 
One can assume that those embeddings differ signifficantly for different meaning, but are quite similar for the same meaning of a word.
What you would do is:

1. run BERT with sentences containing your word "tell"
2. extract the embeddings for the word "tell" from the last layer of BERT
3. try to cluster the specific embeddings to different meanings. If you already have predefined meanings and some example sentences, you can even try to train a clasifier.

[Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/identifying-the-right-meaning-of-the-words-using-bert-817eef2ac1f0) is a blog entry showing the feasability of such an approach.